# Particular example of a non-abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

There exist various (equivalent) ways to phrase when a category is abelian. I like the following: A category $\mathcal{C}$ is *abelian* if

1. It has a zero object $0$,
2. It has all binary biproducts,
3. It has all kernels and cokernels,

such that

4. the biproduct makes all hom-sets abelian groups, and
5. for every $f\colon X \to Y$, the canonical map $\operatorname{coker}(\ker f \to X) \to \ker (Y \to \operatorname{coker} f)$ is a natural isomorphism.

I vaguely remember that in one lecture I attended, I was shown an example of a category that had properties 1.–4., and $\operatorname{coker}(\ker f \to X)$ and $\ker (Y \to \operatorname{coker} f)$ were isomorphic for every $f\colon X\to Y$, *but not through the canonical map*. Hence, the category was not abelian.

I don't remember the example. Do you know one? I vaguely remember there was something with polynomials or formal power series with infinitely many variables… don't remember the details. Anyway, if you know that example, highly appreciated, but so is any other example.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41722/is-every-balanced-pre-abelian-category-abelian

Comment: Or this, rather: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41353/abelian-categories-vs-additive-categories (Banach spaces are mentioned)